# a new material [that] they say is as soft as cotton

Tags: relative-pronouns

Can the relative pronoun "that" be omitted in the following?

> A group of researchers has developed a new material **that** they say is as soft as cotton but as strong as Kevlar and as conductive as many metals.

Comment: It can be dropped, but it's better left in because of the length of the following clause. There should be a comma after *Kevlar*, to separate the comment on the property of conductivity from the opposition *soft... but... strong*.

Comment: If it can be dropped, it is something not covered in ESL grammars, which say the relative pronoun referring to subject position in a relative clause cannot be omitted. E.g. I read the book [that] was sent to me last Friday.

Comment: If you have the answer, why did you post a question about it?

Comment: I wanted to check if my understanding is correct. Or if the ESL grammars are correct.

Comment: To my mind, in the example you just posted, "that" can't be dropped. It can be dropped in the OP example. Maybe someone else will post an opinion.

Comment: It seems that the parenthetical "they say" is being funny.

Comment: Please share whatever research you found and why you think the relative pronoun *that* can or cannot be omitted.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but until someone can convince me otherwise, I believe that the relativiser ***that*** can *always* be omitted in such contexts. You can't omit *just* the relativiser in *I read the book [**that was**] sent to me last Friday* because it's firmly attached to a ***verb*** (but as implied by my square brackets, we can certainly delete the word *pair*, even there).

Answer (score 2):

> A group of researchers has developed a new material that they say is as soft as cotton but as strong as Kevlar and as conductive as many metals.

*they say* is an **interruption** and if removed should not affect the grammar of the sentence.  For clarity, we remove this interruption and get

> A group of researchers has developed a new material that is as soft as cotton but as strong as Kevlar, and as conductive as many metals. [comma added as suggested by @Jack O'Flaherty]

*that* is the **subject** of the relative clause and hence cannot be deleted **alone**.

> I read the book that was sent to me last Friday.

Similarly,  *that* is the **subject** of the relative clause and hence cannot be deleted **alone**.

There are ways to reduce relative clauses with relative pronouns acting as **subjects**, as described [below.](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/relative-clauses/)

**Restrictive** Relative Clauses

> **Subject** pronouns can be deleted if –ing is added to the verb.

> I like the paintings that hang in the SASB North lobby.

> I like the paintings hanging in the SASB North lobby.

**Non-restrictive** Relative Clauses

> **Subject** pronouns with “be” verbs can be deleted in **non-restrictive** clauses.

> I am moving to Louisville, KY, which is home to the Muhammad Ali Museum.

> I am moving to Louisville, KY, home to the Muhammad Ali Museum.

> My mother, who is an excellent cook, is thinking of opening a restaurant.

> My mother, an excellent cook, is thinking of opening a restaurant.

More examples are found in this [link.](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107)

> The product, which seemed perfect in many ways, failed to succeed in the market. Reduced: The product, perfect in many ways, failed to succeed in the market.

> The boy who was pleased by his grades went out with his friends to celebrate. Reduced: The boy, pleased by his grades, went out with his friends to celebrate.

> The box, which was on the table, was made in Italy. Reduced: The box on the table was made in Italy.

> The woman who was at the meeting spoke about business in Europe. Reduced: The woman at the meeting spoke about business in Europe.

As shown above, relative clauses with their relative pronouns acting as **subjects** may be reduced in certain situations, in certain ways.   Their relative pronouns cannot be deleted **alone**.